# Layer conv2d_53 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I'm getting the following error while executing the following Python code for image classification.

```
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Conv2D
    from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
    from keras.layers import Flatten
    from keras.layers import Dense


    # Initialising the CNN
    classifier = Sequential()

    # Step 1 - Convolution
    classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))
```

While I'm executing the step 1 here, I'm getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-230-373aa5a74134>", line 1, in <module>
    classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))

  File "C:\Users\naveenn\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 467, in add
    layer(x)

  File "C:\Users\naveenn\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 575, in __call__
    self.assert_input_compatibility(inputs)

  File "C:\Users\naveenn\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 448, in assert_input_compatibility
    str(inputs) + '. All inputs to the layer '

ValueError: Layer conv2d_55 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>. Full input: [<tf.Tensor 'conv2d_55_input:0' shape=(?, 64, 64, 3) dtype=float32>]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.
```

If I run the code inside `classifier.add()`, Its working fine for me and not returning any error. The code I have mentioned below

`A = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu')`

Here I'm using keras 2.1.5 and tensorflow 1.2.1

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error locally, meaning that it is a problem in some other code that you are also running. Also include the complete error message, including stack traces.

Comment: This might be a version error - [I also can't reproduce your problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDlx5.png).

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I have included the complete error messages. Please check it. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: Can you restart your python kernel and retry? You only have one `Conv2D` in your sample code but your error message says `conv2d_55` which implies there were *at least* 55 more `conv2d` operations defined in the graph. (TF's default naming goes `conv2d`, `conv2d_1`, etc)

Comment: @droooze I have updated my tensorflow and its working now. Thank you

Comment: @GPhilo Thanks for your kind information.